# How to uninstall node v14 from MacOS 10.15?

Tags: node.js, macos

(macOS noob here)
I downloaded nodejs v14 LTS macOS installer from `https://nodejs.org/en/download/` and installed it. Now I want to uninstall it, I am not able to find it in Applications nor I find any other way to uninstall it, How do I uninstall nodejs?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Execute this commands in your terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm ~/.nvm ~/node_modules ~/.node-gyp ~/.npmrc ~/.node_repl_history
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/node-debug /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node-gyp
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/share/man/man1/npm*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node /usr/local/include/node_modules
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/lib/node
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/node
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
```

References:
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/delphi/how+uninstall+node+mac
https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/

Comment: Thanks that worked! but I think there should be a better way of uninstalling it :)

Comment: @MurtuzaZ It's better to use helper apps like n or nvm to manage Node installation next time.

Comment: Another one for the list: `/usr/local/share/man/man1/npx*`.

Comment: After the steps "node -v" still shows a version number so I execute "which node" (which is also mentioned in the reference". I also had node installed via homebrew so I just did a "brew uninstall node" and now it is totally removed :)